# Facebook Graph API v 2.2 with passport.js: profile picture returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I'm using passport.js to perform Facebook authentication in node.js. Everything works fine except user profile picture. I tried these approaches:

```
user.facebook.picture = profile.user_photos[0].value;

user.facebook.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.facebook.id + '/picture?height=350&width=250';
```

And also adding access token:

```
user.facebook.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.facebook.id + '/picture?height=350&width=250' + "&access_token=" + user.facebook.token;
```

However, on clientside facebook picture returns undefined. What might be the possible solution?

Comment: Can you please check what are you getting for *graph.facebook.com/{UserProfileId}/picture* uri

Comment: I'm getting exactly what I need. Somehow your question pushed me to try another option, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem, but in very peculiar way. 
Instead of using

```
user.facebook.picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.facebook.id + '/picture?height=350&width=250';
```

in passport.js configuration, I defined picture in routes.js like that:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user,
        picture: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + req.user.facebook.id + '/picture?height=350&width=250'
    });
});
```

Comment: i guess the problem was related to wiring up *request locals* for *ejs* template, not from fb passport.